# Output terms for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

I was able to echo out all terms belonging to a custom taxonomy using the code below:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'my_post_type','number' => '999');
$terms = get_terms( 'my_taxo',
          [
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'orderby' => 'wpse_last_word',
          ] , $args );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
    echo '' . $term->name . ''; 
}
```

This code provides the results I want on my localhost (xampp). Basically, it outputs all of the terms assigned to a particular post. But when I upload the code to a live server, the code no longer works as expected. Instead, it shows all the terms without filtering them. I even updates the PHP version on my live server match to the local server; still no luck.

Can anyone point out the issue on my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong. I don't know how it is working in your localhost. Cause-

1. You are calling `get_terms()` with 3 parameters which actually accepts 2 parameters. The last one is extra.
2. And secondly `get_terms()` returns all the terms of a taxonomy, not the terms associated with a post.

For getting the terms associated for a post you can use [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms).

**Usage of `wp_get_post_terms` inside *WordPress* loop-**

For each post you'll get the post's terms by calling `wp_get_post_terms` like below-

```
//Do something if a specific array value exists within a post
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'your_taxonomy', array("fields" => "all"));
// Then you can run a foreach loop to show the taxonomy terms infront.
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    echo $term_single->slug; //do something here
}
```

And for outside of the loop-

```
// Do something if a specific array value exists within a post
// And somehow you need to get the post ID to pas it to below.
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'your_taxonomy', array("fields" => "all"));
// Then you can run a foreach loop to show the taxonomy terms infront.
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    echo $term_single->slug; //do something here
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you show me the script to use.

Comment: Have you visited the link ? @rosh8111

Comment: Thanks, i'll check the codex and let you know if it works, thanks for pointing it out.- @the_dramatist

Comment: Hi, I have tested all the scripts out there nothing out putting my term names of the post belongs to CPT. Can you be kind enough to publish the code that do the magic, please note my code is outside loop, I'm currently using                                                                                  
   $args = array('post_type' => 'projects','number' => '1');
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'Client',array("fields" => "names"), $args);
 foreach( $terms as $term ){
 echo '<h5>' . $term->name . '</h5>'; }

Comment: Will you please clear what you are trying to achieve ? Better you edit the question and clear it more ! @rosh8111

Comment: Ok, I have a custom post type called "projects", in that I have created a taxonomy called "Clients", which I will enter clients on the backend. So each time a project is published I will select a client which I wanted to show in front end.

Comment: So, you need to show the terms associated with a single post, right ? And inside ***WordPress*** loop or outside ***WordPress*** loop ? If outside of the loop then in which template `single.php` or `archive.php` ?

Comment: @rosh8111 have a look to the updated answer.

Comment: I have my own custom template, actually this page load in custom single.php page associate with a custom post type. I'll update you with results, thanks for the assist.

Comment: I have check the code you gave me, I'm afraid it's not fetching any results, simply empty. I have tried even with query post. Nada..

Comment: First replace `your_taxonomy` with your `clients` taxonomy name. Then do a `print_r($term_list)` give the result here with a screenshot of your custom taxonomy admin page. @rosh8111

Comment: [link]http://pad10.net/assets/tax_error.jpg, find the attache screenshot of my setup and results i'm getting.

Comment: Obviously this would not return anything. You need to pass the post ID to `$post_id`. Here in your case the `$post_id` is empty I guess. you can get post ID from `global $post` then `$post->ID`.

Answer (score 0):

After few researchs I found below script do the work, thanks @the_dramatist pointing me to a right direction, I had use global $post, but not in a correct way

```
global $post;
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'myCPT', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy');                   
foreach($terms as $term_single) {
echo '' . $term_single->slug. '';
}
endwhile;
```

If anyone getting empty results after this, just delete the categories and re-create and apply them.